# Approximation for three homogeneous equations wihtout zeros as results

Tags: approximation, homogeneous-equation

I have three formulas to calculate dilutions of three chemicals ($x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$):

$x_1 * 20 / (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) * 0.75 / 7 = 0.9$ 
$x_2 * 20 / (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) * 0.75 / 7 = 0.1$ 
$x_3 * 10 / (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) * 0.75 / 7 = 0.2$

I know, this is a homogeneous equation system. Since I am needing all chemicals, $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ must not be zero. To this end, I am looking for approximated results with $x_1 > 0$, $x_2 > 0$ and $x_3 > 0$.

Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The equations are not independent, and there are no solutions since adding the following gives $1 = 49/75$.

$$
\begin{cases}
   x_1 / (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) = 0.9/20 \cdot 7 / 0.75 = 21/50
\\ x_2 / (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) = 0.1/20 \cdot 7 / 0.75 = 7/150
\\ x_3 / (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) = 0.2/10 \cdot 7 / 0.75 = 14/75
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is not consistent and you want to reconcile it.

A way to do it is to define a norm
$$\Phi(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\sum_{i=1}^3 w_i\big[\text{lhs}_i-\text{rhs}_i\big]^2$$ and to minimize it under positivity constraints.

Making the story short, with all $w_i=1$, this would give
$$x_1=1 \qquad \qquad x_2=\frac{47}{215} \qquad \qquad x_3=\frac{188}{215}$$ For these values, the rhs are $\frac{43}{42}=1.024$, $\frac{47}{210}=0.224$ and $\frac{47}{105}=0.448$